# DPLL(T) algorithm used in Z3 (linear arithmetic)

Tags: algorithm, z3, smt, dpll

The arithmetic solver of Z3 is developed based on DPLL(T) and Simplex (described in [this paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/cav06.pdf)). And I do not understand how Z3 perform the backtrack when a conflict explanation is generated. I give an example:

The linear arithmetic formula is:

`(2x1+x2≤200 OR 3x1+x2≤250) AND (2x1+x2+x3≤200 OR 4x1+2x2+x3≤400)
AND x1≥50 AND x2≥50 AND x3≥60`

after asserting `2x1+x2≤200`, `2x1+x2+x3≤200`, `x1≥50`, `x2≥50` and `x3≥60` successively, it yields a conflict explanation set `{2x1+x2+x3≤200, x1≥50, x2≥50, x3≥60}`.

My question is, how then the backtrack is performed when this conflict set is generated?

Answer (score 2):

The main paper to read for understanding the algorithm is:

```
 A Fast Linear-Arithmetic Solver for DPLL(T)
 Bruno Dutertre,  Leonardo de Moura
```

Download: [.pdf](http://leodemoura.github.io/files/cav06.pdf)